# Java ProcessBuilder Cannot Find File Specified

Tags: java, python, file, processbuilder

```
import java.io.*;
class RunTest {
public static void main(String a[]) {
    try {
        String prg = "import sys\nprint int(sys.argv[1])+int(sys.argv[2])\n";
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("test1.py"));
        out.write(prg);
        int number1 = 1;
        int number2 = 2; 
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("python","test1.py",""+number1,""+number2);
        Process p = pb.start();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        int ret = new Integer(in.readLine()).intValue();
        System.out.println("value is : "+ret);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

}

When I run this code (I'm using Eclipse), I get the stack trace:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
>       at RunTest.main(RunTest.java:11)
>   Caused by: java.io.IOException: CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.create(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.(ProcessImpl.java:386)
>       at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:137)
>       at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
>       ... 1 more

Anyone have any idea why and what I can do?

Thanks!

Comment: Is the `python` command in the path?  Can you run it from the command line?

Comment: Python is in the path and I just checked and it does work from the command line, but still not in Eclipse...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, this is probably really unhelpful, but somehow, it just started working. No idea why or how, because I haven't changed anything. Eclipse basically just restarted itself randomly and now it works! Sorry I couldn't post a solution that will help others, but thanks anyway for your help @MadProgrammer and @Elliott !

Comment: disappointing.... because i've got the same issue here. If anybody has any tips let's here them!

Answer (score 0):

You have to `flush()` and you should `close()` (which will also `flush()`) after you write to the `File`.

```
out.write(prg);
out.close(); // <-- add this.
```

Also, you'll need to add `python` to your PATH.

Comment: Woops sorry I took that line out when I was messing around trying to make it work before and forgot to put it back in, but it still has the same problem. Python is already in my path. Also, I