# Calling python file from java throws error

Tags: java, python, cmd

I am trying to call python file from java. but it throws following error.

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified
```

The code that I have tried is :

```
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("python C:\\Project\\Script\\Test.py");
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
    System.out.println(in.readLine());
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: I think following link may help you, [Java ProcessBuilder Cannot Find File Specified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28204342/java-processbuilder-cannot-find-file-specified)

Answer (score 0):

Runtime.exec expects a file with no path information to be in the user dir and not in the directory you specify to use as working directory.
Try using this code once.

```
Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
Process prs;
File Dir_temp = new File("C:\\Project\\Script\\");
prs = rt.exec(new File(Dir_temp, "Test.py").getAbsolutePath(), null, Dir_temp);
prs.waitFor();
prs.destroy();
```

Comment: again it throws  java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "C:\Project\FBLogin\Test.py" (in directory "C:\Project\Script"): CreateProcess error=193, %1 is not a valid Win32 application